# get devise cant be blank registration form error despite the fact that I filled the fields out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

my form code:
[form code](http://pastebin.com/fSR0NY9a)

The fields are fieled out i checked it with firefox debugger.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing "protected_attributes" gem resolves my problem